# Can i pass jsonobject like this?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Can i use the following class to get the data from the server.

```
public class ProductDetail implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    public JSONObject configOptions = null;
}

On putting a check on this:
if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
    performClick();
}
```

This method will redirect the user directly to login page if he is not logged in. Otherwise it will perform the click. But it goes to login and this following error comes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1388)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1335)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
                                                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
                                                                         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:138)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1191)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:385)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1357)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1262)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638)
                                                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313)
                                                                         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2975)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3497)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)



Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
                                                                         at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1383)
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1335) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638) 
                                                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
                                                                         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(Fragment.java:138) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1191) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:385) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1357) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1262) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:638) 
                                                                         at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1313) 
                                                                         at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1096) 
                                                                         at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:663) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2975) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3497) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Comment: `java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json.JSONObject` what do you think that could mean?

Answer (score 0):

It seems ConfigOptions (JsonObject) is not serializable. You can convert the JsonObject to String and try to serialize it.